# Height is not working

Tags: php, html, css, height

i have this files:

index.php:

```
<body>
    <div id="page">
        <div id="header"><h1>BANNER</h1></div>
        <div id="pmenu"><?php include 'template/pmenu.php' ?></div><br>
        <div id="text">
            <div id="left">Menu<br>menuMenu<br>menuMenu<br>menu</div>
            <div id="center">ccsal<br>saccsal<br>saccsal<br>sa</div>
            <div id="right">rright<br>rirright<br>rirright<br>ri</div><br>
        </div></div><br>
    </body>
```

pmenu.php

```
<nav>
<div id="pmenuli">HOME</div> 
<div id="pmenuli">HTML</div> 
<div id="pmenuli">CSS</div> 
<div id="pmenuli">PHP</div> 
<div id="pmenuli">JAVA SCRIPT</div> 
</nav>
```

and style.css:

```
body{text-align: center; background-color: rgb(185, 185, 185);}
#page{ background-color: rgb(225, 225, 225); width:1124px; height: auto; margin:auto;
border-left:2px solid blue;
border-right:2px solid blue;
border-top:2px solid blue;
border-bottom:2px solid rgb(25, 25, 25);}
#pmenu{height: 30px;
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,0% 0%,0% 70%,from(#6a6a6a),to(#222));
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(0% 22px 90deg,#222,#6a6a6a);
-moz-border-radius: 4px;
-webkit-border-radius: 4px;
border-radius: 4px;
display: block;
margin: 0 auto 20px;
border: 1px solid #222;
position: relative;
background-color: #6a6a6a;
color: white;
vertical-align: middle;
box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.75);
width: 1118px;}
#pmenuli:hover
{height: 30px;
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,0% 0%,0% 70%,from(#222),to(#6a6a6a));
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(0% 22px 90deg,#6a6a6a,#222);
-moz-border-radius: 4px;
-webkit-border-radius: 4px;
border-radius: 4px;
display: block;
margin: 0 auto 20px;
border: 1px solid #222;
position: relative;}
#pmenuli{
border: 1px solid black;
float: left;
width: 150px;
height: 29px;
font: 20px Times new roman,Sans-serif;}
a:link{color: white;}
v:link{color: white;}
#left,#center,#right{float: left;}
#left{width: 155px}
#center{width: 555px}
#right{width: 155px}
```

but if i add text in div with id "text", the height of the #page is the same. A screenshoot:
http://artur99.hostyd.com/Untitled.png

i tried:

```
height: auto;
height: max-content;
height: content-box;
height: border-box;
```

But still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `overflow:auto` to `#page`.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/WWz3m/)**

When you float the child elements of a div, in order to have the div extend to cover them you need to set the overflow to auto or hidden.

Comment: @LuckySoni - actually it's not and it's the preferred way, especially over an old hack like clearfix, and it creates no problems.

Answer (score 0):

Clear your floats.. use [clearfix](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/)

the parent with floated child lose their height as the floated elements are removed from the normal document flow.. you need to apply clearfix to such parent elements

example:
The elemets with "nav" and "content" classes are being floated (removed from normal document flow) hence the parent "container" needs clearfix

```
<div class="container group"> <!-- Applying clearfix to the parent with floated elemets -->
   <div class="nav">
     Some nav items
   </div>
   <div class="content">
     Some content
   </div>       
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.nav{
   width: 40%;
   float: left;
 }
 .content{
   width: 60%;
   float: left;
 }
.group:before,
.group:after {
   content: "";
   display: table;
} 
.group:after {
   clear: both;
}
.group {
   zoom: 1; /* For IE 6/7 (trigger hasLayout) */
}
```

Comment: its a long code, i think the overflow:auto is a better solution